# Print pyramid pattern n times underneath each other

Tags: java, for-loop

I know how to print a pyramid pattern, but I want to print them underneath each other n times. I tried to solve it with for loop, but the output isn't what I wanted. The first pyramid pattern is good, but the others are wrong. Tried with triangle and it gives correct output. What is the difference between the two pattern?. The program is in Java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int height;
        int stars =1;
        int level;
        System.out.println("Pyramid pattern.");
        System.out.print("Please give the height: ");
        height = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How many times to print: ");
        level = sc.nextInt();
        int szelesseg = magassag - 1;
        if (magassag <= 0) {
            System.out.println("A magasságnak pozitívnak kell lennie.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < szintek; h++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < magassag; i++){
            for (int j = szelesseg; j>i; j-- )
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < stars; k++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            stars += 2;
            System.out.println();
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, source code is pasted. So the problem is the output. It draws more then the required pyramid pattern.

Comment: I haven't tried to to look too hard, but it appears that you never reset `csillagok` to it's initial value, whatever it does.

Comment: And how can I reset csillagok which means stars to it's initial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the star count is being incremented by two for each line printed in the for loop, but it is never reset, so it starts the second triangle much larger than 1. The easiest solution would just be to set it equal to 1 at the start of the outermost for loop. Here is what I used:

```
        for (int h = 0; h < level; h++) {
            stars = 1;    
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
                for (int j = szelesseg; j>i; j-- ) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < stars; k++){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                stars += 2;
                System.out.println();
           }
       }
```

Which outputs :

```
  *
 ***
*****
  *
 ***
*****
  *
 ***
*****
```

I translated some of the variable names to English because they seemed to be declared in English but referenced in Hungarian (maybe it was just my browser trying to translate). I also hard coded the values to 3 because I didn't feel like dealing with scanner on an online compiler. Hopefully this helps!

Edit: To help stop the program if invalid number / -1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height;
    int stars =1;
    int level;
    System.out.println("Pyramid pattern.");
    System.out.print("Please give the height: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();
    if (height > 0) {
        System.out.print("How many times to print: ");
        level = sc.nextInt();
        int szelesseg = magassag - 1;
    //Rest of handling code goes here
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("A magasságnak pozitívnak kell lennie.");
    }
```

Here the check for -1 happens right after receiving the input. The rest of the logic is put in the successful case, meaning that it will only happen if the input is greater than 0. In the else case there is the error message. This means it will print as soon as the first input fails or another error occurs.

Comment: One more question if you can help me! The program must stop after the first input is negative, but it asks the second input and only after that stops.

System.out.println("Fenyőfalomb rajzoló program.");
        System.out.print("Kérem a magasságot: ");
        height = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Kérem a szintek számát: ");
        level = sc.nextInt();
        int szelesseg = height - 1;
        if (height <= 0) {
            System.out.println("A magasság csak pozitív lehet.");
        }
        else if (level <= 0) {
            System.out.println("csak negatív);

Comment: That's because your if statement (if magassag <= 0) occurs after the second input, you should move the if statement up to where the first input happens and check if height <= 0 there.

Comment: Understand, but if I try to move the second input after the if, it shows an error, illegal expression. I'm too tired now :) maybe tomorrow I correct it. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Hi! Can you explain me how to use two user input with exceptions using if. I really don't know how to use them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much!